# Stop NSThread execution when application will be sent in background mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, nsthread, runloop

I have the following problem in my iphone application:

I have a NSThread who works with a TCP socket. When this thread is performing a very long function, I send in the background mode the application. When I return from this background thread starts from where it left off before bringing in the background the application. Is there a way to stop the execution of that method (my thread) even though it has not been completed?